# Hatcher's proof that every manifold $M$ has an orientable two sheeted covering space $\tilde{M}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am confused by Hatcher's proof on page 234 that every manifold $M$ has an orientable two sheeted covering space $(\tilde M)$.

He constructs  it as follows:

$$\tilde{M}=\{\mu_x \mid x \in M \text{ and } \mu_x \text{ is a local orientation of } M \text{ at } x\}$$

The map $\mu_x \mapsto x$ is a two to one surjection $\tilde{M} \rightarrow M$ and he topologizes it as follows:

Given an open ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n \subset M$ of finite radius and a generator $\mu_B \in H_n(M\mid B)$, let $U(\mu_B)$ be the set of all $\mu_x \in \tilde{M}$ such that $x \in B$ and $\mu_x$ is the image of $\mu_B$ under the natural map $H_n(M\mid B) \rightarrow H_n(M\mid x)$.

This set forms a basis for a topology on $\tilde{M}$ and makes the projection $\tilde{M} \rightarrow M$ a convering space.

> Here is where I get lost:
>
> The manifold $\tilde{M}$ is orientable since each point $\mu_x \in \tilde{M}$ has a canonical local orientation given by the element $\tilde{\mu}_x \in H_n(\tilde{M}\mid\mu_x)$ corresponding to $\mu_x$ under the isomorphisms $H_n(\tilde{M}\mid\mu_x) \approx H_n(U(\mu_B)\mid\mu_x) \approx H_n(B\mid x)$ and by construction these local orientations satisfy the local consistency condition necessary to satisfy a global orientation.
>
> I know the first isomorphism comes from excision, but where does the second isomorphism come from? Also, this could be an issue of me not comprehending the isomorphism, but why exactly is the local consistency condition then satisfied?

Comment: The second comes from the map $\mu_x\to x$. The local consistency comes from that of the local orientation.